# Could not find the latest documentations (user guide) for MAAS 2.1.1 (Metal as a Service) in MAAS website?

Tags: 16.04, juju, maas, canonical

I could'nt find the user guide documentation for the latest MAAS 2.1.1 in the internet. The software package 2.1.1 is released but there is no documents for this version. The new UI of MAAS 2.1.1 differs from the previous versions.

Answer (score 2):

2.1 documentation is available here:
https://docs.ubuntu.com/maas/2.1/en/